# Possible NullReferenceException in a non-instantiatable sealed class

Tags: c#, null

Considering the following:

```
public sealed class RequestType
{
    private RequestType()
    {
    }

    private RequestType(string value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    private string Value { get; }

    public static RequestType Get => new RequestType("GET");
    public static RequestType Post => new RequestType("POST");
    public static RequestType Put => new RequestType("PUT");
    public static RequestType Head => new RequestType("HEAD");
    public static RequestType Delete => new RequestType("DELETE");
    public static RequestType Patch => new RequestType("PATCH");
    public static RequestType Options => new RequestType("OPTIONS");

    ....

    public static bool operator ==(RequestType r, string o)
    {
        return r.Equals(o.ToUpperInvariant());
    }

    ....
}
```

I'm receiving `Possible NullReferenceException` on both `RequestType` and `object`. The possibility of `object` being `null` is true, but it's not for `RequestType` since all properties are already pre-defined and there's no way of instantiating it, apparently.

So, what should be the right action in this situation? Is it good practice to check for null anyways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> all properties are already pre-defined and there's no way of instantiating it

is irrelevant to

> RequestType can't be null

For a parameter to be null, you don't need to instantiate it (being null is the complete opposite of that!). You just write `null`, and having "pre-defined" instances doesn't prevent people from doing that at all. You can't prevent people from doing that unless you use a value type, like an enum.

For example, this will make your code throw a NRE, even if you added a null check on `o`:

```
((RequestType)null) == "some string"
```

So yes, you should still check for nulls.

Comment: Oh~ Ok, so, to make it non-nullable i should be using a `struct` instead, right? But, this will make it possible to instantiate it. Is there a way to avoid both of these cases?

Comment: @Explisam Hmm, I can't think of any _really_ good ideas. Your type certainly should be a value type, but C# value types require a "0" value, which your type lacks... Anyway, try the `_isValid` solution at the end of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36605403/5133585). You don't actually need to check the `_isValid` flag in `==`, since `Value` would be null, and the comparison would always be false anyway, given that you already checked `o` for null.

Comment: I won't sleep at night if i use `_isValid` to workaround it. I'll just throw a null exception. I was just hoping for a design time error type of solution.